# Can I use nested queries with @Query in JPA?

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, jpql

I have a task entity, which holds all user's tasks in the company. so it is @ManytoOne relationship. (many tasks belongs to specific user)

I want to calculate the sum:

```
(task_sum_of_user1 - avg)^2 + (task_sum_of_user2 - avg)^2 + .... (task_sum_of_user_N - avg)^2
```

I tested a query in Postgresql database and this one works:

```
select sum(v.t_sum) from(select (s.user_tasks + 10)^2 t_sum from (select count(*) user_tasks from Task t GROUP BY t.employee_id) s) v
```

But when I run the query in @Query annotation it doesn't seems to work:

```
@Query("select sum(v.t_sum) from(select (s.user_tasks + 10)^2 t_sum from (select count(*) user_tasks from Task t GROUP BY t.employee_id) s) v
")
```

it throws exception *"unexpected token: ("*
What am I missing?

Comment: Why not create this as native query? e.g. ```@Query(value="YOUR_QUERY", nativeQuery=true)```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use dbms's specific functions inside `@Query`, as it takes jpql as `value`. You can create a custom `@Repository` with native query, like that:

```
entityManager
    .createNativeQuery("select sum(v.t_sum) from(select (s.user_tasks + 10)^2 t_sum from (select count(*) user_tasks from Task t GROUP BY t.employee_id) s) v")
    .getSingleResult();
```

You need to map the result somehow or provide it as the second parameter of `createNativeQuery`.

As **@Billy Frost** noticed, adding `nativeQuery` flag as true to `@Query` is also an option.

Comment: ah, yes, that is also an option;)